# Obtain substring

Tags: c++, string, substring

I have written a small client-server interface, which uses simple MySQL-like text strings (encrypted) to communicate between client and server.
Example of a text string to sign a user in:

```
SIGNIN WHERE USER="test" AND PASSWORD="1234"
```

I'm looking to obtain the `USER` and `PASSWORD` values to check via a local MySQL database, but I'm stumped on this since the `USER` and `PASSWORD` fields are mostly always different sizes.

In Lua, it could be possible to use something similar to this to get the values:

```
local username, password = 'SIGNIN WHERE USER="%s" AND PASSWORD="%s"';
```

Is there something similar in C++ to get substrings out of strings in a similar way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is `sscanf`

Good documentation, and example use:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/sscanf

The basic implementation for your case:

```
  std::string exampleInput { "SIGNIN WHERE USER=\"foo\" AND PASSWORD=\"bar\" " };
  char username[64] {0};
  char password[64] {0};
  std::sscanf(exampleInput.c_str(), "SIGNIN WHERE USER=%63s AND PASSWORD=%63s",
              username, password);
```

**edit**: As mentioned below, added limits to parsed string lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one option, using a [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  string input = "SIGNIN WHERE USER=\"test\" AND PASSWORD=\"1234\"";
  stringstream ss(input);
  ss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '"');
  stringbuf username;
  ss.get(username, '"');
  ss.ignore(1);
  ss.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '"');
  stringbuf password;
  ss.get(password, '"');
  cout << "username: " << username.str() << endl
       << "password: " << password.str() << endl;
}
```

Working code here: http://codepad.org/B64WNz4O